# How to set only one property in object with useState?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have an object as state in react:

```
{course: {…}, userIDs: Array(2), usersNumber: 2}
```

Where `course` is such an object:

```
price : 100
promotion : null
comments : []
```

What I want to do is add a new object to the `comments` array and leave all other properties unchanged. How to do it with `useState` ?

Comment: Could you add whole component?

Comment: In general, you would create a new object, deep copy your current state object into the new object, make the changes in the new object, and then setState to the new object.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the spread operator to spread all the current values and only add a new comment to the new comments array:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  course: {
    price: 100,
    promotion: null,
    comments: [],
  },
  userIDs: [],
  usersNumber: 2
});

function updateState() {
  setState((currState) => ({
    ...currState,
    course: {
      ...currState.course,
      comments: [
        ..currState.course.comments,
        { thisIsANew: "comment" },
      ]
    }
  });
}
```